# GET Request "Not Valid JSON" Fetch React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am fetching the following data using React "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe, here is your board ID 1540383426" but I am receiving the following error: "Error: Unexpected token 'W', "Welcome to"... is not valid JSON."

Does anybody happen to know why I am getting this error?

```
  componentDidMount() { 
  // Invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree)
  // If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/NewGame")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) =>{
          this.setState = ({
            isLoaded: true,
            board: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
    }
```

```
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, board } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    } else {
      return {
        board
      }
    }
  }
}

  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
  root.render(<TicTacToe />);
```

Comment: Please try removing `.then(res => res.json())` line. Here, you are trying to parse the `result` into JSON but in your case, `result` is just plain text.